# beginbfchar mapping with multiple values

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have encounter following character mapping in one PDF.

```
1 beginbfchar
<21><0009 000d 0020 00a0>
endbfchar
1 beginbfchar
<5b><002d 00ad 2010>
endbfchar
```

How to interpret this mapping?

Comment: I assume those are **ToUnicode** CMaps. If there weren't those spaces, each of those glyph codes would be mapped to the respective **sequence of UTF-16 code points**, the standard example from the specification being a `ﬄ` ligature glyph being mapped to `<00660066006C>`, i.e. `ffl`. Considering the codes given in your example, though, the space characters appear to separate **alternative mappings** for the same glyph. E.g. an empty glyph might alternatively represent a horizontal tab, a regular space or a non-breaking space. I don't have a normative reference for this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but how should I decide what to use when I am trying to extract the text?

Comment: I've only seen such alternatives for a very few types of glyphs, foremost the empty glyph and the '-' glyph. I'd introduce special treatment for these few types of glyphs (or types of Unicode character selections): In the first case usually the choice is between different kinds of white spaces; unless you are up to in-depth graphical analysis of the page appearance, I'd always choose the normal space character. ...

Comment: For '-' types of selections one might look whether the glyph is followed by a digit of even surrounded by digits, or whether it is surrounded by letters; then choose an Unicode character appropriate for that use. Etc etc

Comment: Okay thanks I ll try to figure it out. :)